# Can I export a PostgreSQL database from Heroku and Import as a PostGIS database in Digital Ocean?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, heroku

Disclaimer: This may be a dumb question. This is honestly way over my head... one of the pitfalls of using Heroku for too long.

I have a PostgreSQL database on Heroku. Now I'm migrating to Digital Ocean where I will be using PostgreSQL with PostGIS on Ubuntu 14.04. I would like to export my PostgreSQL database from Heroku and import it into Digital Ocean.

Is this possible? Is there any potential issues I should look out for?

Comment: I thing nothing can stop you from taking a dump and restore it elsewhere... See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export